# Can templates be used in C++ to link functionality to a class member name?

Tags: c++, templates, methods, member

This problem is recurring and bothers me since years. It's probably a known thing but somehow I haven't got yet to that book to answer it.

I have an application that creates messages. The messages contain fields that have either a value or are null which are set by methods like setField1()/setNullField1().

I'd like to write code which encode such fields in the message in a generic way, e.g. using templates not macros.
The code is generic as the algorithm is the same but the methods that are supposed to be called for a field depend on that field name, e.g. setField1/setNullField1.

It seems to me that it should be possible in C++ to build this relation between field name and the methods that have to be called (which include field names in the method name) without using macros.

Can you please share some ideas about how to do that?
I might have an incorrect understanding about the limits of templates vs macros so please correct me if this is the case

*Update*
As code was requested to describe a problem a bit here is some code https://onlinegdb.com/cu-Gpsahz but be aware that this is exactly my problem, I'm not able to write this code and not sure if this is even the proper strategy (e.g. to use an unordered_map)

Comment: No you can't use templates to fill out function/variable names for you. This is, even while I definitely prefer templates, one of the reasons I still use macros every now and then. The closest thing I know without macros is to inject lambda functions to do the set/get into the common code. (wher then the function parameter is the templated one)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I'm looking not for a direct solution but perhaps using the "one more level of indirection" to solve this

Comment: Not exactly sure if this is helpful but I mean something like this : https://onlinegdb.com/FJsLWS2w3x

Comment: @PepijnKramer In your code there is no member and no method name depended on that. In my understanding you're simply calling the two methods as common_code will be generated twice: one time because you call it with a pointer to different member methods. Also, you could have spare your _int and _double as they're anyway resolvable via parameter type, see https://onlinegdb.com/LkabGZzn8

Comment: c++ has no reflection but it has `std::unordererd_map` that you can use to map names to member functions

Comment: please include a code example. Especially when asking how to automate / avoid / simplify some code it is necessary that you show the code

Comment: Are you asking for something like `struct Message { std::optional<int> Field1; };`?

Comment: The keyword you are looking for introspection or, more generally, reflection. Later C++ standards will support this. The [Qt property system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/properties.html) fakes it by tagging fields and using code generation to synthesize property objects that can be read or written.

Comment: Perhaps show some code that uses macros for us in order to understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @n.m. I need something along this line, https://onlinegdb.com/Z4UhEGO-F Here I simply define a macro and use ##field to make the link between methods of Encoder and OutputMessage member name